# DrawingArea: fill area outside a region

Tags: c++, c, cairo, gtkmm

I have followed [this gtkmm tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-cairo-drawing-arcs.html.en) on how to draw shapes and fill them with colors (e.g. A red disc on a transparent background). I was also able, from this example, to derive another example with a red disc on a blue background.

However, what I would really need is a transparent disc with a blue background that fills everything **minus the disc area**, which should stay transparent.

So with cairo, the usual workflow is:

1. Create a surface
2. Draw a shape (e.g. draw a circle)
3. Fill the circle, so that it becomes a disc.

I would need some workflow that achieves something like this instead:

1. Create a surface
2. Draw a shape (e.g. draw a circle)
3. Fill the area **outside** the circle, so that I have a colored background with a transparent "hole" in the middle.

I have done some research on this on the web but all examples seem to assume that we want to fill the inner region of a shape (which I must admit is more typical).

How could I do this?

P.S. I have added the C tag because I don't mind if you prefer to use C (or even Python).

Comment: Would it be possible to have an explanation as to why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw your circle and draw a rectangle containing all the visible area. Set the cairo fill rule to even/odd. Fill. Done.

```
cairo_save(cr); // Save the state
cairo_arc(cr, 42, 42, 21, 0, 2*M_PI); // Draw circle
cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, width, height); // Rectangle containing everything
cairo_set_fill_rule(cr, CAIRO_FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD);
cairo_fill(cr);
cairo_restore(cr); // Restore default fill rule (optional; pairs with save above)
```

Comment: Ok, your solution is intriguing. I have looked briefly at the even/odd rule documentation but have not yet understood that it has to do with my situation. I have not yet had time to play with it but I will definitely try this around the end of the week and give some feedback.

Comment: Thanks to the rectangle, everything is contained in the area that should be draw. Thanks to the circle, everything in the circle is contained another time (= twice). Even/Odd only fills the oddly contained area, so everything in the rectangle, but not the circle, because that part is contained twice (which is even).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, The function of 'Draw outside the circle' is complex to the graphic framework. It may also be ambiguous if you draw more than one circle filled outside.

As graphic shapes drawn later are placed 'on' the ones drawn former. What is needed is that draw a rectangle to fill the entire graphic context before drawing other shapes. This is defined as **clear** with the **background color** in some frameworks.

the workflow would seem like:
1.  Create the surface.
2.  Draw the background colored with what outside the circle.
3.  Draw the circle filled with a specific color, e.g. white.
As a result, the circle would cover the background.

If insist on draw the circle first, please search [Flood Fill Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), which is used to draw on images. However, it is needless and costly to achieve the screen pixels and play such algorithms when drawing on screen.

---

I find 
[Example Application: Creating a Clock with Cairo](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-drawing-clock-example.html.en) in the later section of the book you provide.
That seems help.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that there is no simple way to do this because to the 'on top of' model of the framework, right? As for the workflow you are suggesting, I used that to have my red disc on a blue background.

Comment: It's something about the order. If you paint the whole window (graphic context) with blue, and then draw an white-filled circle. That's the same as you draw an circle on the white window and then paint the outer area with blue.

Comment: But white is almost never the widget's background color. It depends on themes and platforms. Although, if there was a way to find the default background for the widget on that specific platform according to it's style, it would work. I could trade white for it.